# change type from id to subclassed nsmanagedobject

Tags: cocoa

I need this operation bsc method receive id and i like to using dot syntax to set object later.
Currently i do by this way. But maybe somebody know more elegant way?

```
-(NSError *) updateObject:(id)object operation:(NSInteger)operation;
{
CurrentCompany *obj1 = nil;
 ...
CompanyStuff *obj2 = nil;


if ([[[(CurrentCompany *)object entity] name] isEqualToString:@"CurrentCompany"]) obj1 = (CurrentCompany *)object;
if ([[[(CompanyStuff *)object entity] name] isEqualToString:@"CompanyStuff"]) obj2 = (CompanyStuff *)object;

NSLog(@"UpdatedObject:%@",obj1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If these classes conform to a common protocol or inherit from a common superclass that declares the properties, you can just statically type the variable as that protocol or superclass. If neither of these are the case, it doesn't seem like they should be treated interchangeably anyway.

Also, this isn't really related, but the explicit cast from `id` to the specific class is pointless. You can just assign.

Comment: @Chunk peace of code appreciated. u mean something like CurrentCompany *obj1 = &object?

Comment: @Alex: `object` already holds a pointer to an object. `&object` is a pointer to the `object` variable, not to an object. Trying to assign that pointer to a variable typed as holding a pointer to an object (e.g., `CurrentCompany *`) will cause problems.

Comment: @Peter Hosey what kind of problem i can expect?

Comment: Trying to send a message to a pointer to something that is not an object will cause a crash.